# Mitigating botnet brute force attack with Javascript Detection?

Tags: security

Hi this is my first post here. I am developing a website project with public user registration and log in functions. Right now, I am conceptualizing the logic flow of the whole project and currently stuck at the authentication and security part.

I have googled and unable to find an answer. I also searched sof but effort is futile as well. **What I want to ask is quite specific.**

From what I read at other sof posts, it seems that to mitigate a brute-force attack, ip banning or time delay after n number of attempted log ins is one of the best solutions. Of course not forgetting whitelisting and blacklisting and Captcha. Of course I already plan to implement the above-mentioned techniques.(maybe not captcha)

**My question is, is it possible to detect javascript enabled or unabled to block illegitimate log-in attempts** base on the assumption that bot-net or 'hackers' **do not** use a javascript enabled browser to do their 'work'?

> For example, "*if js disabled, stop the 'rendering' of the log-in
>   form. //brute force attempt detected*"

Finally, this assumption is base on the fact that all of my users will have a js enabled browser in order to use my website.

This approach will be run concurrent with other mitigate methods.

Please enlighten. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not reliably or efficiently.  You can't really trust anything that comes from the client side.

Anything you ask the client to do in javascript to prove that javascript is present can be impersonated.  Forcing them to impersonate will force them to be more intelligent and expend more resources, which might be a win for you.

Answer (score 0):

While u2702 makes a good point, I think it's good to keep in mind that just because a solution doesn't dissuade *all* attackers doesn't mean it should be abandoned. In fact, I think this is a quite good method to deter the vast majority of bots.

To answer the question at hand, you could have all prospective users calculate the MD5 of a value you've generated using a cryptographically secure random function. Faking this without javascript would be more-or-less impossible (as far as I can see).

Disclaimer: Implementation of this method will ban Richard Stallman and people who use NoScript from your site.

Comment: The MD5 check may do more harm than good.  If you ask the client to calculate an MD5, you have to check the MD5 on the server side (which takes resources) and keep track of which MD5 you asked them to calculate (which takes resources).  If you keep a server side db of clients and MD5-challenges, a DDOS attack could overwhelm your DB.  If you don't track, you're vulnerable to replay attacks where they calculate the MD5 once and send it over and over (of course, on the server side you have to calculate the MD5 every time).